# Django login auth form

Tags: html, django

I trying to grasp this new field of webbprogramming and is it possible to make the user login from a form which is built into the html file itself? If so, how can i achieve this?

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login </a>
    <form class="dropdown-menu p-4 dropdown-menu-right" method="post" action="#">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_username">Username</label>
            <input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="user.name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_password">Password</label>
            <input id="id_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        {% if form.errors %}
        <p class=" label label-danger">
            Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.
        </p>
        {% endif %}
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deal with the view.

In you views.py you should have :

```
user = authenticate(username = "username", password = "password")
login(request, user)
```